# Sized Deallocation Feature In Memory Management in C++1y

Tags: memory-management, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, c++14

Sized Deallocation feature has been proposed to include in C++1y. However I wanted to understand how it would ***affect/improve*** the current c++ ***low-level memory management***?

This proposal is in **[N3778](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3778.html)**, which states following about the intent of this.

> With ***C++11***, programmers may define a static member function operator
>   delete that takes a size parameter indicating the size of the object
>   to be deleted. The equivalent global operator delete is not available.
>   This omission has unfortunate performance consequences.
>
> Modern memory allocators often allocate in size categories, and, for
>   space efficiency reasons, do not store the size of the object near the
>   object. Deallocation then requires searching for the size category
>   store that contains the object. This search can be expensive,
>   particularly as the search data structures are often not in memory
>   caches. The solution is to ***permit implementations and programmers
>   to define sized versions of the global operator delete***. The
>   compiler shall call the sized version in preference to the unsized
>   version when the sized version is available.

Well from above paragraph, it look like the size information which operator delete require can be maintained and hence passed by used program. This would avoid any search for the size while deallocation. But as per my understanding, while allocating, memory management store the size information in some sort of header(explained *boundary-tag method in **[dlmalloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html)***), which would be used while deallocation.

```
T* p = new T();
// Now size information would be stored in the header
// *(char*)(p - 0x4) = size;
// This would be used when we delete the memory????.
delete p;
```

If size information is stored in the header, why deallocation require searching for it?
It looks like I am missing something obvious and did not understand this concepts completely.

Additionally,how this feature can be used in program while dealing with the low level memory management in C++. Hope that somebody will help me to understand these concept.

Comment: *"and, for space efficiency reasons, do not store the size of the object near the object."* They're talking about other allocation strategies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in your quote:

> [Modern memory allocators] for space efficiency reasons, do not store the size of the object near the object.

Increasing the size of every allocation in order to add explicit size information is obviously going to use more memory than alternatives such as storing the size information once per allocation pool, or supplying the information upon deallocation.